# How do I perform weighted loss in multiple outputs on a same model in Tensorflow?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, rnn

How do I perform weighted loss in multiple outputs on a same model in `Tensorflow`? This means I am using a model that is intended to have 3 outputs. I did this because I would like the network to learn the relationships of the input variables. More specifically, this is multi-output regression.

The output model shape is like the following:

```
tf.Tensor: id=606, shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.01483282,  2.9515972 , -0.07268244],
       [-0.8814691 ,  2.543654  ,  0.08576971],
       [-0.6933001 ,  1.3419302 , -0.25192362]], dtype=float32)
```

The `model.summary()` is below:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn (SimpleRNN)       (3, 32)                   1152      
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (3, 3)                    99        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,251
Trainable params: 1,251
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The shape is (3,3) with 1st index being the batch size (the network is an RNN). I need to set weighted loss for each of the outputs. I tried the argument `weighted_losses` on `tf.keras.models.Model` but the error returned:

```
ValueError: When passing a list as loss_weights, it should have one entry per model output. The model has 1 outputs
```

What is the correct method to have weighted loss using a single model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to have a model trained on multiple "tasks". If so, this is what it could look like:

```
input_data = <your input sequence input>
output_data = <array of size (N, 3)>

out1_weight, out2_weight, out3_weight = <your weights for each output to adjust loss contribution>

input = Input()
simple_rnn = SimpleRNN()(input)

# Define the three outputs
out1 = Dense(1)(simple_rnn)
out2 = Dense(1)(simple_rnn)
out3 = Dense(1)(simple_rnn)

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[out1, out2, out3], loss_weights=[out1_weight, out2_weight, out3_weight])

model.compile(<whatever params>)
model.fit(input_data, [output_data[:, 0], output_data[:, 1], output_data[:, 2]])
```

Comment: As an improvement to the template,
The Input layer has input_shape and batch_size,
`input = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape,
                               batch_size=<integer>)`

For the creation of Model, the argument `loss_weights` is part of the `model.compile()` method.